# How does this proof of law of sines determine equal angles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I was reading over [this](http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/173/law-sines-cosines.pdf) proof of the law of sines and they say that $\angle CAB = \angle DOB$ because of "basic geometry". I do not get it though, how can you say that the angles are equal?

Comment: The link is not working for me. Regardless, though, it is preferable to make questions self-contained, whenever possible. Please [edit] your question to include relevant excerpts and diagrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is referring to a property of [inscribed angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Property):

> The measure of the intercepted arc (equal to its central angle) is exactly twice the measure of the inscribed angle.

So $m\angle COB = 2 m\angle CAB$, and they bisected segment $CB$ to halve the angle.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I knew that inscribed angles could be equal if they mark the same arc, but I didnt know the theorem about the central central angle.

Answer (score 2):

$\angle CAB$ is an inscribed angle; $\angle DOB$ is half of a central angle through the same arc, so the angles are equal.

See http://www.mathopenref.com/arccentralangletheorem.html for more.